# A fair die is rolled five times. What is the probability that the largest number rolled is 5?

Tags: probability

I was confused how to approach this problem. It is provided in the sample paper for mma of isi masters exam of 2021.

Comment: @DuncanRamage  That is a different question.  In that case, you can use symmetry to conclude that the answer is $1/2$.  Here, you have to subtract the probability that no roll results in a number higher than $4$ from the probability that no roll results in a number higher than $5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Exactly true. I think I've seen this question before on MSE but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: @DavidK  I found this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696623/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-largest-of-the-three-dice-rolls).

Answer (score 4):

The probability the highest number is less than $5$ is $(4 / 6)^5$, since every die roll must be $1, 2, 3,$ or $4$.  The probability the highest number is no greater than $5$ is $(5/6)^5$, since every die roll must be $1, 2, 3, 4,$ or $5$.  Thus, the probability the highest number is exactly $5$ is
$$\left(\frac56\right)^5 - \left(\frac46\right)^5 \;=\; \frac{2101}{7776} \;\approx \;0.27.$$