# We take k-element sequences with values from the set $[n]$. For each, we find the smallest value, and then sum these. Why the sum $=1^k+...+ n^k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

We consider all k-element sequences with values from the set $[n] = \{1,2 ,..., n \}$. For each such list, we determine the smallest value, and then sum these values. Show that the sum is equal to:

$$1^k + 2^k + 3^k + ... + n^k$$

Example, for $k = 2$ and $n = \{ 1,2 \}$:

In that case, get $4$ seqences. Those are: $11$, $22$, $12$, $21$. Therefore, we take smallest values from each of those $4$ sequences. These will be: $1,2,1,1$. We sum them up and get $5$.

Why would that be the case?

---

I know that there are $n^k$ k-element sequences with values from the set $[n]$. From each of those we need to take the smallest value. It will be $1$ for $n^k - (n-1)^{k}$ of those sqeuences (we take all possible sequences and subtract those without any $1$). Therefore we have $(n^k - (n-1)^{k}) \cdot 1$.

- For $2$ we have: $(n-1)^k - (n-2)^{k}$ sequences because we can take all possible sequences without $1$ and subtract those without any $1$ and $2$
- And so on...

Therefore we get:

$$\big(n^k - (n-1)^{k} \big) \cdot 1 + \big( (n-1)^k - (n-2)^{k} \big) \cdot 2 + ... + \big( 1^k - 0^{k} \big) \cdot n$$

But that doesn't look like: $1^k + 2^k + 3^k + ... + n^k$, so I don't know what to do...

Comment: For $(n,k)=(2,2)$ there is only one sequence we can take, namely $\{1,2\}$, right?  the least element of that is $1$ so the answer in that case is $1$.  But you claim it should be $1^2+2^2=5$.  Am I misunderstanding something?  More broadly, the case $(n,n)$ always gives $1$ if I have understood the rules correctly.

Comment: And why do you say there are $n^k$ subsequences ?  Surely there are $\binom nk$.

Comment: No, we take all possible sequences made of $k$ elements with values in set $n$. Therefore, if we have $k = 2$ and $n = \{1,2 \}$, we get $4$ seqences. Those are: $11$, $22$, $12$, $21$. Then we take smallest values from each of those $4$ sequences. These will be: $1, 2, 1, 1$. We um them up and get $5$, which works fine with the formula stated above. I'm sorry, maybe my description was not clear enough. @lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, the number of sequences with smallest term equel to $i$ is
$$S_i=(n+1-i)^k-(n-i)^k.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{i=1}^niS_i=\sum_{i=1}^ni(n+1-i)^k-\sum_{i=1}^ni(n-i)^k$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)(n-i)^k-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i(n-i)^k$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)^k=1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k.$$

Comment: Looks good, but why: $\sum^n_{i=1}i(n-i)^k = \sum^{n-1}_{i=0}i(n-i)^k $ ? @user14111

Comment: Because $i(n-i)^k=0$ when $i=0$ and also (since we assume $k\gt0$) when $i=n$, the terms indexed by $i=0$ and $i=n$ can be included or omitted without affecting the sum.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^ni(n-i)^k=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(n-i)^k+0=0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(n-i)^k=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i(n-i)^k$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a probability problem in disguise. Let $f(n,k)$ denote the sum you are interested in, and let $E(n,k)$ denote the expected value of the minimum of $k$ independent rolls of a fair $n$-sided die with sides numbered from $1$ to $n$. Plainly,
$$E(n,k)=\frac{f(n,k)}{n^k}.$$
In my answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696623/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-largest-of-the-three-dice-rolls/1696755#1696755) I used the method of indicator variables to derive the formula
$$E(n,k)=n^{-k}\sum_{i=1}^ni^k$$
from which it follows that
$$f(n,k)=n^kE(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^k.$$
However, your straightforward solution (completed in @user14111's answer) seems simpler.